# C# USB driver from C++: SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I've a problem trying to call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail from C#. It always returns 1784 error code ("The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation"). This is my C# code:

```
Guid GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DFU = new Guid(0x3fe809ab, 0xfb91, 0x4cb5, 0xa6, 0x43, 0x69, 0x67, 0x0d, 0x52,0x36,0x6e);

        Guid classGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DFU;

        IntPtr hDevInfo = Win32.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, Win32.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | Win32.DIGCF_PRESENT);
        if (hDevInfo.ToInt32() == Win32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("read hardware information error");
        }
        else
        {
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
            devInfoData.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
            devInfoData.classGuid = Guid.Empty;
            devInfoData.devInst = 0;
            devInfoData.reserved = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool result = Win32.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, devInfoData);
            if (false == result)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (error != Win32.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }

            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA ifData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
            ifData.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(ifData);
            ifData.Flags = 0;
            ifData.InterfaceClassGuid = Guid.Empty;
            ifData.Reserved = IntPtr.Zero;

            bool result2 = Win32.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, IntPtr.Zero, ref classGuid, i, ifData);
            if(result2 == false)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (error != Win32.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }

            uint needed;

            // This returns: needed=160, result3=false and error=122 ("The data area passed to a system call is too small")
            bool result3 = Win32.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, ifData, null, 0, out needed, null);
            if(result3 == false)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }

            IntPtr detailDataBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA ifDetailsData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA();
            ifDetailsData.devicePath = new byte[needed - 4];   
            ifDetailsData.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(ifDetailsData);

            uint nBytes = needed;

            // This returns always: error = 1784
            bool result4 = Win32.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, ifData, ifDetailsData, nBytes, out needed, null);
            if (result4 == false)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (error != Win32.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }
        }
```

Classe Win32:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace USB_test
{
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public Guid classGuid;
    public uint devInst;
    public IntPtr reserved;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public byte[] devicePath;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
    public uint Flags;
    public IntPtr Reserved;
}

public class Win32
{
    public static uint ANYSIZE_ARRAY = 1000;

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid ClassGuid, IntPtr Enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, uint Flags);   

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr lpInfoSet, UInt32 dwIndex, SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData);

    [DllImport(@"setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(IntPtr hDevInfo, IntPtr devInfo, ref Guid interfaceClassGuid, uint memberIndex, SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData);

    [DllImport(@"setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr hDevInfo, SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData, SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetailData, uint deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, out uint requiredSize, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData);

    public const int DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x02;
    public const int DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x10;
    public const int SPDRP_DEVICEDESC = (0x00000000);
    public const long ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259L;
    }
}
```

If it can help someone, this is the solution:

```
IntPtr detailDataBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)needed);
Marshal.WriteInt32(detailDataBuffer, (IntPtr.Size == 4) ? (4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize) : 8);
uint nBytes = needed;

bool result4 = Win32.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, ifData, detailDataBuffer, nBytes, out needed, null);
if (result4 == false)
{
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (error != Win32.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
}

IntPtr pDevicePathName = new IntPtr(detailDataBuffer.ToInt32() + 4);
String devicePathName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pDevicePathName);
```

Additional Note:  If running on a 64-bit machine, or forced 64-bit mode, the above line for the pointer to pDevicePathName would reference a 64-bit pointer, not 32

IntPtr pDevicePathName = new IntPtr(detailDataBuffer.ToInt64() + 8);

Comment: Late coming and as we know Windows stuff changes, including their DLLs.  Do you have any updates to this?  I tried with full copy/paste, few missing vars, but nothing else.  Keep failing on calls 3 & 4 results even after changing signature to IntPtr for 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The struct is a variable sized structure which cannot be marshalled automatically. You'll need to do so yourself.

You'll need to remove the `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` type. It's no use to you. Change the declaration of `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` to:

```
[DllImport(@"setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
    IntPtr hDevInfo, 
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData, 
    IntPtr deviceInterfaceDetailData, 
    uint deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, 
    out uint requiredSize, 
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData
);
```

Pass `IntPtr.Zero` in the first call to `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`. Then allocate a buffer of the required size by calling `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. Then write the size into the first 4 bytes of that buffer. Then call `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` again.

Something along these lines:

```
bool result3 = Win32.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, ifData, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 
    out needed, null);
if(!result3)
{
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
// expect that result3 is false and that error is ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122, 
// and needed is the required size

IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)needed);
try
{
    uint size = needed;
    Marshal.WriteInt32(DeviceInterfaceDetailData, (int)size);
    bool result4 = Win32.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, ifData, 
        DeviceInterfaceDetailData, size, out needed, null);
    if(!result4)
    {
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
    // do whatever you need with DeviceInterfaceDetailData
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(DeviceInterfaceDetailData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much David for your help and patience!

Comment: You don't want to write the returned size.  Per MSDN: The cbSize member always contains the size of the fixed part of the data structure, not a size reflecting the variable-length string at the end.  That line should write (IntPtr.Size == 8 ? 8 : 4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize)

Comment: That last bit was really important!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the [answer of David Hoffmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67527654/20138168) doesn't work. But he inspired me to this solution:

```
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)requiredSize);
int cbSize = sizeof(DWORD) + 2 * sizeof(CHAR); // cbSize + empty DevicePath
Marshal.WriteInt32(buffer, cbSize);
deviceInterfaceInfoData.cbSize = (DWORD)Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInterfaceInfoData);

if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
    deviceInfoSet,
    ref deviceInterfaceData,
    buffer,
    requiredSize,
    out requiredSize,
    ref deviceInterfaceInfoData))
    throw new Win32Exception(error);

int devicePathSize = (int)requiredSize - sizeof(DWORD); // cbSize
char[] devicePathChars = new char[devicePathSize / sizeof(char)];
int offset = sizeof(DWORD); // cbSize
Marshal.Copy(IntPtr.Add(buffer, offset), devicePathChars, 0, devicePathChars.Length);
string devicePath = new(devicePathChars, 0, devicePathChars.Length - 1); // Remove NULL terminator
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
```