# Can I use SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces to get a DevicePath from SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail when no InterfaceClassGUID is known?

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, setupapi

**Overview...**

I have read [How to get device interface GUID for a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892299/how-to-get-device-interface-guid-for-a-device) and [How to open a handle to a device using its Device Instance ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741925/how-to-open-a-handle-to-a-device-using-its-device-instance-id), but I'm still confused about how I am to (or whether I should even) use [SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinterfaces) paired with [SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetaila) to get a [DevicePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/ns-setupapi-sp_device_interface_detail_data_a) that can be opened with *CreateFile* to access the device when no [device interface class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-device-interface-classes) GUID is known. My question is based on the MSDN article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-write-a-windows-desktop-app-that-communicates-with-a-usb-device) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device) which rely on these functions.

**More details...**

The high level of my problem is I've got an audio USB device I need to send control transfer commands. To do so, I want to use WinUSB's [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/ff540046(v=vs.85)#winusb), and to do *that* I need to get a handle to the device via CreateFile. Unfortunately, there is no .inf file associated with the device and so there is no known device interface class GUID. If one plugs the device in, Windows associates with it [usbaudio.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/usb-audio-class-system-driver--usbaudio-sys-) as the driver. To start talking over WinUSB, I use [libwdi](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi) to install WinUSB as the device driver so that I can communicate with it via the WinUSB API. To accomplish the install of WinUSB, libwdi dynamically creates a self-signed .cat and .inf file pair, which unfortunately has no device interface class defined. In fact, the INF file has the following in it:

```
[NoDeviceInterfaceGUID]
; Avoids adding a DeviceInterfaceGUID for generic driver
```

So, despite the fact I now have swapped out usbaudio.sys for winusb.sys, I'm unable to communicate with the device.

At first I thought maybe I should try using [GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-usb-device), reasoning that this is WinUSB and therefore seen as a generic USB device. But, if I invoke

```
SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(_deviceList,
   &devInfo,
   &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE,
   0,
   &usbInterface)
```

it fails and GetLastError returns 259, or **ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS** immediately. I'm assuming this means it doesn't implement the interface?

So, in general, when no interface class guid is known, am I able to use the aforementioned functions in any form to get the full device path?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first you need to get a *device information set* for devices that implement the interface via `SetupDiGetClassDevs`, then pick one of the devices and read its device interface data, and use that to get the device interface detail that contains the device path.

Example:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <usbioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL DevicePath(_In_ LPCGUID interfaceGuid, DWORD instance)
{
    BOOL result = FALSE;
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_W devInterfaceDetailData = NULL;

    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevsW(interfaceGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    if(hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        goto cleanup;

    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devInterfaceData;
    devInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    if(!SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, interfaceGuid, instance, &devInterfaceData))
        goto cleanup;

    // Call this with an empty buffer to the required size of the structure.
    ULONG requiredSize;
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW(hDevInfo, &devInterfaceData, NULL, 0, &requiredSize, NULL);
    if(GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        goto cleanup;

    devInterfaceDetailData = malloc(requiredSize);
    if(!devInterfaceDetailData)
        goto cleanup;

    devInterfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
    if(!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW(hDevInfo, &devInterfaceData, devInterfaceDetailData, requiredSize, &requiredSize, NULL))
        goto cleanup;

    wprintf(L"%s\n", devInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath);
    result = TRUE;

cleanup:
    if(hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    free(devInterfaceDetailData);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    for(DWORD i = 0; DevicePath(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, i); ++i)
       ;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! That's precisely what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Comment: ...in retrospect, I didn't understand how device information sets worked, and this revealed it. Basically, the device information elements have a linked list of interfaces attached to them, in my code, despite grabbing the right device, I do the following to look for the USB interface: 

SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(_deviceList,
   &devInfo,
   &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE,
   0,
   &usbInterface)

The 0th element in the linked list for devInfo didn't necessarily implement that interface, and so it failed. Sitting it in a loop like you did solved it. Awesome.

Comment: @Ben Not quite. `SetupDiGetClassDevs` queries for devices with the interface, so all the elements have the interface.  The loop just iterates through all the instances.  I could put the for loop inside the DevicePath function and only call SetupDiGetClassDevs once.

Comment: @Ben You didn’t show your SetupDiGetClassDevs call, but I’m guessing you passed NULL for the first parameter, and got all devices, not just the ones that have the interface you want.

Comment: ....OK. I reread what you had said: it loops through the INSTANCES, not the INTERFACES. I understand now. I get it. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer and educate.